# Returning a weak_ptr member variable

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have the following `TreeNode` class which can store a reference to its parent node as well as a vector of pointers to all its children.

**TreeNode**

```
class TreeNode : public std::enable_shared_from_this<TreeNode>
{
private:
    int val_;
    std::weak_ptr<TreeNode> parent_;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<TreeNode>> children_;
public:

    TreeNode(int val) : val_(val) {}

    void addChild(std::shared_ptr<TreeNode> child)
    {
        child->parent_ = shared_from_this();
        children_.push_back(std::move(child));
    }

    const int& getVal() const
    {
        return val_;
    }

    std::weak_ptr<TreeNode> getParent()
    {
        return parent_;
    }
};
```

The `parent_` is stored as a `weak_ptr` so that there's no circular dependency / memory leak between a parent and its children.

**Main**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::shared_ptr<TreeNode> parent = std::make_shared<TreeNode>(1);
    std::shared_ptr<TreeNode> child = std::make_shared<TreeNode>(2);

    parent->addChild(child);

    // child->getParent()->getVal(); not possible
    return 0;
}
```

When using this class I would like to access the value of any nodes' parent (... otherwise why store a parent), but since `parent_` is a `weak_ptr`, I can't call any member functions on it.

I understand there's some "hacks" around this like using `lock` to extract the `shared_ptr` from a `weak_ptr`, but I feel like this makes the API unwieldy. I'm wondering what the recommended C++11 way of returning a `weak_ptr` is such that it's still usable.

EDIT:

I probably shouldn't have called `lock` a "hack" but rather inelegant from an API standpoint.

For example, if I wanted access to `parent_` I would have to do something like this

**Main**

```
if (!child->getParent()->expired())
{
    std::cout << child->getParent()->lock()->getVal() << std::endl;
}
```

This seems rather verbose so I'm wondering if there are any language features I can take advantage of to avoid doing all of this.

Comment: That's not a hack. In order to use what a `weak_ptr` points at you have to confirm that the pointed-at object sill exists and make sure it continues to exist while you use it. That's what `lock` is for.

Comment: What makes you think `lock` is a hack? `weak_ptr` would be unusable without it

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have used the term "hack", I have edit the original post to illustrate why this may lead to a verbose API.

Comment: Discuss with your rubber duck what happens if the object is destroyed immediately after `if (!child->getParent()->expired())` confirms that the object still exists.

Comment: Yes, I fully agree that this check is necessary. But other languages can do things like "Optional Binding" to make the syntax less verbose. I was curious if there was such a syntax in C++

Comment: Groovy. You understand what's going on. Glad I didn't try to answer this one formally. To my knowledge there is no built-in helper and it would be a violation of C++'s you only pay for what you ask for policy to silently imply a lock. I admit it would be damn useful, but you wouldn't have to acknowledge you're paying the conversion tax. But since you know whoever calls `getParent` is going to do something with that parent, I'd return a `shared_ptr` and hide the `lock` inside `getParent`.

Comment: Thanks for confirming! And yeah... thought about that but it would still mean the user has to check if the `shared_ptr` is actually pointing to something. Would rather enforce an `.expired()` check as its more semantically clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way around calling `lock` on a `weak_ptr`, the whole point of `weak_ptr` is that it doesn't count towards reference counting of the object that it is pointing to, while still allowing to use the control block to check if the object is valid or not, and then get a `shared_ptr`.

For me it looks like `parent_` shouldn't be a `weak_ptr`, but a raw pointer. Using raw pointers isn't bad practice or 'not modern', they just shouldn't own any memory. With that you could juts check if it is a `nullptr` or not, to check if a node has a parent.

Also your example of using `lock` on a `weak_ptr` is wrong. `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` are made to be concurrently created and destroyed by many threads, and that's where most of their use cases are.

```cpp
if (!child->getParent()->expired())
{
    std::cout << child->getParent()->lock()->getVal() << std::endl;
}
```

In your example you first check if a pointer is still valid using `expired` member function, and if it is you use `lock` to get a `shared_ptr` that will contribute to object reference count. If there's more then one thread that might be using that pointer, after your `expired` and before `lock` calls your reference count could hit 0, and object could be deleted from memory. You will then get a `nullptr shared_ptr` from `lock`, and undefined behavior when you dereference it.

If you keep using `weak_ptr` do it like this.

```cpp
if(auto parent_ptr = child->getParent()->lock())
{
   // parent_ptr is shared_ptr that is not null here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I see no reason against using a raw pointer in my case. Additionally, is there any reason you wrote that `if` statement with `auto` ?

Comment: *With that you could juts check if it is a `nullptr` or not, to check if a node has a parent.* There's potential for screw-up here if a parent is removed from the graph. Destruction of the parent would have to call through to all of the children and null their parent pointer. And any one operating on that returned raw pointer will have no clue that the object is gone. If you're going to use `shared_ptr`, use it right and get all of the guarantees. When you don't someone writes code assuming they're safe and gets a nasty shock because they aren't.

Comment: @Carpetfizz , whatever path you choose, go all in. Don't go half and half. It never works.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you, I didn't consider the fact that I would have to manually null all the parent references of the children. For this reason alone, I would rather use a `weak_ptr` and go through the necessary checks.